# Reverse words of string

Tags: string, unit-testing, rust

I'm trying to show spaces between the words after processing the string but I'm getting

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
left: `"abcd"`,
right: `"a b c d"`', src/main.rs:11:5
```

How can I fix it?

```
fn reverse_words(words: &str) -> String {
    words.split_whitespace().map(reverse_word).collect()
}

fn reverse_word(word: &str) -> String {
    word.chars().rev().collect();
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(reverse_words("apple"), "elppa");
    assert_eq!(reverse_words("a b c d"), "a b c d");
    assert_eq!(reverse_words("double  spaced  words"), "elbuod  decaps  sdrow");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You split the input on whitespace but when you collect it, it's joined without any separator. To fix, you can collect it into a `Vec<String>` and then call `.join(" ")` on it:

```rust
fn reverse_words(words: &str) -> String {
    words.split_whitespace().map(reverse_word).collect::<Vec<_>>().join(" ")
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1df4a941de50125bf1f1e121497043d7)

---

A more efficient implementation of `reverse_words` that does not allocate an intermediate Vec:

```rust
fn reverse_words(words: &str) -> String {
    words
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(reverse_word)
        .enumerate()
        .fold(
            String::new(),
            |acc, (i, word)| if i == 0 { word } else { acc + " " + &word },
        )
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b5c547cd2f1479682e978bfc31ff236)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without (wastefully?) collecting into a `Vec`?

Comment: @BallpointBen there is itertools::intersperse and an unstable API of the same name in std

Comment: In this case, a plain intersperse will still require allocations since our iterator is of type `String` and so the separator must also be a `String`. I've added a solution based on `fold`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fn reverse_words(words: &str) -> String {
    words.to_string()
        .split(" ")
        .map(reverse_string)
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .join(" ")
}

fn reverse_string(s: &str) -> String {
    s.to_string()
        .chars()
        .rev()
        .collect::<String>()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).